# How to produce given number of quad in math

Tags: spacing, macros, recursion

We know that `\qquad` equals `\quad\quad`, then is there a way to define a command like `\myquad{5}` to produce five `\quad`?

I think there are two way:

1. get the length of `\quad`, then 
   `\newcommand{\myquad}[1]{\hspace{#1*lengthofquad}}`
2. define a function and load it recursively, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\quad` sets a length of `1em`, with multiples `X` of it being of length `Xem`. So we can define `\myquad[<num>]` with `<num>` being optional (default of `1`), to produce a space of `<num>em`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myquad}[1][1]{\hspace*{#1em}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

x \quad x \par
x \myquad[1] x

x \quad\quad\qquad x \par
x \myquad[4] x

x \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad x \par
x \myquad[10] x

\end{document}
```

We use `\hspace*` to insert a space regardless of whether you're at the start, middle or end of a rule.

Comment: works like a charm!!

Comment: note that this freezes the meaning to the length of 1em in the preamble. so `\myquad` unlike `\quad` will not depend on the current font, I think not having the `\setlength` and then `\newcommand{\myquad}[1][1]{\hspace*{#1em}\ignorespaces}` gives a more natural interpretation. (@user19832)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: True. Thanks, I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 7):

Here is version using a loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\Quad[1][1]{\foreach \Quaddy in {1,...,#1}{\quad}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

  x \quad x \par
  x \Quad[1] x

  x \quad\quad\qquad x \par
  x \Quad[4] x

  x \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad x \par
  x \Quad[10] x

\end{document}
```

with output:

[image]

Personally, I prefer the more direct approach in Werner's answer.

Comment: I try to use `tlmgr install pgffor` but not found, do you mean `pgf` instead?

Comment: @user19832 Good point, I should have mentioned this. The`pgffor` package is part of the bigger [pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package that allows you to use the for-loops from `pgf` without pulling in all of the `pgf` package, which is quite large. If you use `tlmgr` to install `pgf` then, I believe, you will also get the package `pgffor.sty` but you can instead just use `\usepackage{pgf}` in the MWE above.

Answer (score 4):

You can look up how `\quad` and `\qquad` are defined, either in the [LaTeX source](https://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/latex2e-public/trunk/base/) or by asking LaTeX itself:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\show\quad
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
> \quad=macro:
->\hskip 1em\relax .
 \show\quad

?        

*\show\qquad
> \qquad=macro:
->\hskip 2em\relax .
 \show\qquad

? 

*
! Emergency stop.
 \show\qquad

No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

In many cases this will place you in a maze of twisty commands, all subtly different, but here it's pretty straightforward. A quad is a horizontal space of 1[em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)) (the nominal width of a capital M in the current font).

```
\newcommand{\myquad}[1]{\hskip #1 em\relax}
```

or in a more LaTeXish way

```
\newcommand{\myquad}[1]{\hspace{#1 em}}
```